# How To Get Top 5 Column Sum Arranged By Descending Order?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I've a table like this:

```
---------------------------------------
| S No | item     | Col1      | Col2  |
| ------------------------------------|
| 1    | carrot   | 111       | 2     |
| 2    | broccoli | 222       | 3     |
| 3    | spinach  | 333       | 2     |
| 4    | swiss    | 444       | 3     |
| 5    | cheddar  | 5555      | 5     |
| 6    | cheddar  | 6666      | 6     |
| 7    | onion    | 7777      | 3     |
```

There are many columns like Col1, Col2, Coln with all integer values. I want to take sum of all columns and get the name of top 5 columns with their names and sum values as response of query. I can do this with top 5 records but find it hard to do with columns. I'm doing it for rows like this:

```
$q1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `File Name`, `Kudos` FROM `{$_SESSION['username']}` ORDER BY `Kudos` DESC LIMIT 5");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $myCols[] = $row;
} 
print_r($myCols); // Works fine
```

print_r gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => AAAA
            [File Name] => AAAA
            [1] => 343
            [Kudos] => 343
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Test File Again
            [File Name] => Test File Again
            [1] => 45
            [Kudos] => 45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => TEST FILE
            [File Name] => TEST FILE
            [1] => 3
            [Kudos] => 3
        )

)
```

Looks good. 
How do I same for column with maximum sum values for whole column?
 Anyone out there?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add them up and use them in the `order by`:

```
SELECT `File Name`, (col1 + col2 + col3 . . . ) as totalsum
FROM `{$_SESSION['username']}
ORDER BY totalsum DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Bro I want sum of each column separately. I don't want to sum columns.

Comment: I want to sum each column separately and on that result want to get top 5 column names with their sum values. Clearer?